# Traveling sales man algorithm

Tags: data-structures

Can someone help me with the code for traveling sales man :

Code found here: http://www.pracspedia.com/AOA/tsp.html

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int a[10][10],visited[10],n,cost=0;

void get()
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter No. of Cities: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter Cost Matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i < n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Elements of Row # : %d\n",i+1);
        for( j=0;j < n;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        visited[i]=0;
    }
    printf("\n\nThe cost list is:\n\n");
    for( i=0;i < n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        for(j=0;j < n;j++)
            printf("\t%d",a[i][j]);
    }
}

void mincost(int city)
{
    int i,ncity;
    visited[city]=1;    
    printf("%d -->",city+1);
    ncity=least(city);
    if(ncity==999)
    {
        ncity=0;
        printf("%d",ncity+1);
        cost+=a[city][ncity];
        return;
    }
    mincost(ncity);
}

int least(int c)
{
    int i,nc=999;
    int min=999,kmin;
    for(i=0;i < n;i++)
    {
        if((a[c][i]!=0)&&(visited[i]==0))
            if(a[i][c]+a[c][i] < min)
            {
                min=a[i][0]+a[c][i];
                kmin=a[c][i];
                nc=i;
            }
    }
    if(min!=999)
        cost+=kmin;
    return nc;
}

void put()
{
    printf("\n\nMinimum cost:");
    printf("%d",cost);
}

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    get();
    printf("\n\nThe Path is:\n\n");
    mincost(0);
    put();
    getch();
}
```

Matrix :

```
 0 10 15 20
 5 0  9  10
 6 13 0 12
 8 8  9  0
```

The result should be `cost : 35`
But it is giving wrong `cost : 39` and wrong path,

Can someone please fix the code ? or provide the simplest (less code) program that can

1. Show a cost
2. Also show a path ?

Please help. I have tested many programs but none of them gives correct answer.

Comment: I would suggest that you split apart the code, define what each method ought to be doing, and write tests around each function. That way, it will be easier for you and us to understand which specific part of your algorithm needs help.

Comment: The code isn't mine, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You mean, either fix someone else's code you found, or write another for you? You don't even say what route you expected, or was given. Voting to close.

Comment: I already said in question that please fix this code.

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: No, we do not fix someone else's code for you. When you've worked on the code yourself and run into problems, you can do like everyone else and explain the problem you've encountered, include the *relevant portions of your code* here in the question itself, and ask a **specific question** related to that code. See [ask] and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From the  [source-code site](http://www.pracspedia.com/AOA/tsp.html) you can read

> There is small change in the code. The line  min = a[i][0] + a[c][i];
>   should be min = a[i][c] + a[c][i];

Here is the function you've to change:

```
int least(int c)
{
    int i,nc=999;
    int min=999,kmin;
    for(i=0;i < n;i++)
    {
        if((a[c][i]!=0)&&(visited[i]==0))
            if(a[c][i] < min)
            {
                min=a[i][c]+a[c][i];
                kmin=a[c][i];
                nc=i;
            }
    }
    if(min!=999)
        cost+=kmin;
    return nc;
}
```

Comment: If you see code in my question I already applied this but it didn't works

Comment: @Amy you didn't, at least in the code you posted. It's working for me with this change

Comment: Are you getting 35 cost for above matrix?

Comment: can you please help?

Comment: Thanks BetaRunner,  its much appreciated you at least helped. Others users who down voted my question have no humor.